# using contain operator or equivilant

Tags: sas, contain

in SAS how to to use a contain (or alternative) operator when you have more than one set of letters to choose. eg where have_variable= abd, afg, afd, acc and want_variable=abd, afg, afd (containing ab or af only)

Comment: Souinds like a job for **Index** or **Find** functions.

Answer (score 2):

I've Split your have and want list into two tables with multiple records then left joined on Have list to find the matching ones.

[The final table will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHV5.png)

```
/* Create your input String */
data Have;
have="abd , afg , afd , acc";
run;
data Want ;
want="abd , afg , afd";
run;
/* Splint Input strings into Multiple Rows */
data Have_List;
   set Have;
   do i=1 by 0;
   source=lowcase(scan(have,i,','));
   if missing(source) then leave;
   output;
   i+1;
   end;
   keep source ;
run;
data Want_List;
   set Want;
   do i=1 by 0;
   lookup=lowcase(scan(want,i,','));
   if missing(lookup) then leave;
   match='match';
   output;
   i+1;
   end;
   keep lookup match;
run;
/* Create a SQL left join to lookup the matching values */
proc sql;
create table match as 
select h.source as have , COALESCE(w.match,"no-match") as match
from have_list h left join want_list w on h.source=w.lookup;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list in your select statement.

Like that :

```
proc sql;
select * from my_table where have_variable in ('abd','afg','afd','acc') and want_variable in ('abd','afg','afd');
run;
quit;
```

You can even use the in operator in a dataset statement like this :

```
data want;
set mydate;
if have_variable in ('abd','afg','afd','acc') and
want_variable in ('abd','afg','afd');
run;
```

If you want to obtain the variable only containing 2 letters you can use the LIKE :

```
proc sql;
select * from my_table where have_variable like '%ab%' or have_variable like '%af%';
run;
```

in a dataset :

```
data want;
set mydate;
where have_variable like '%ab%' or
have_variable like '%af%';
run;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you only want records that begin with ab or af (rather than contains them anywhere in the string), then you can you `in` followed by `:`.  With this usage, the colon instructs SAS to only search the first n letters in the string, where n is length of the comparison (2 in your example).

Note that this only works in a datastep, not `proc sql`.

```
data have;
input have_var $;
datalines;
abd
afg
afd
acc
;
run;

data _null_;
set have;
where have_var in: ('ab','af');
put _all_;
run;
```